# conflicting types for 'topper',brnchwise

Tags: c, structure

Program to intake 3 students details and subjects(3) marks and

1. display topper
2. students under a branch.

Error is that conflicting types for 'topper','brnchwise'.

I've defined functions before using them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int regno;
    char brnch[3];
    int marks[3];
    int avg;
} s[3];

void mainscrn()
{
    int o;
    char brncho[3];
    printf("enter 1. for displaying topper details\n\t 2.for display all students under a branch");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    switch(o)
    {
    case 1:
        system("CLS");
        printf("the topper details are:");
        topper();
        break;

    case 2:
        system("CLS");
        printf("Enter the  brnch");
        scanf("%s",&brncho);
        system("CLS");
        brnchwise();
        break;
    default:
        printf("pls enter a right option");
        mainscrn();
        break;
    }
}

void topper()
{
    int i,a,count,t=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(s[i].avg>t)
        {
            count=i;
        }
    }
    printf("regno:\t %d\nbranch:\t%s",s[count].regno,s[count].regno);
    printf("\nPress 0 fo main screen");
    scanf("%m",&a);
    if(a==0)
    {
        mainscrn();
    }
}

void brnchwise()
{
    int a,i;
    char brncho[3];
    printf("the sudents are: \n");
    scanf("%s",&brncho);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(brncho,s[i].brnch)==0)
        {
            printf("/n%s",s[i].regno);
        }
    }
    printf("\nPress 0 fo main screen");
    scanf("%m",&a);
    if(a==0)
    {
        mainscrn();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,t;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your detils 1.regno,2.brnch,marks");

        t=0;
        scanf("%d%s",&s[i].regno,&s[i].brnch);
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&s[i].marks[j]);
            t=t+s[i].marks[j];
        }
        s[i].avg=t;
    }
    mainscrn();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it should be pointed out that you forgot `{` after `void mainscrn()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I've defined functions before using them.

Actually, you haven't.  `topper` and `brnchwise` are referenced in `mainscrn`, and they haven't been defined yet at that point.  Since these functions reference each other, you need to add a **declaration** for those functions:

```
void topper(void);
void brnchwise(void);

void mainscrn(void)
{
    ...
}

void topper(void)
{
    ...
}

void brnchwise(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `topper()` and `brnchwise()` in `mainscrn()`, the compiler hasn't seen declarations for them. So it implicitly declares for them with int return (in pre-C99). But the actual definition conflicts with these. Hence, the errors.

Declare the prototype for them at the top of your source file:

```
void topper(void);
void brnchwise(void);
```

Note "implicit int" rule has been removed since C99 and thus your code is invalid in C99 and above.